# Is it OK to spend most of the Ph.D. period in designing & programming systems (vs experimenting and creating experimental results)

Tags: phd, research-process

My PhD. in data science in EU requires mostly a system to design and to develop using some programming language, eventhough it introduces some novel approaches that I showcase through use cases. I am bit worried that my whole research work doesn't produce any experimental results.

Is that OK for a PhD?

Comment: That is a question that only your supervisor(s) can answer as they will be the one(s) evaluating your PhD work and if the should or shouldn't award you a degree for it.

Comment: see also: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/academia-varies-more-than-you-think-it-does-the-movie

Answer (score 0):

Designing and programming aren't quite enough, though it may be necessary in some fields. While it isn't necessary in all cases to have extensive experimental data, it *is* necessary to provide evidence of the value of your programs and designs. That can be done through small studies, perhaps, or thorough theoretical investigations. In your case, probably some small experiments, though your advisor is the proper judge of that.

In more traditional CS, a student might spend a vast amount of time developing, say, a new garbage collection system for a family of languages. That is fine, but it isn't enough for a degree. You also have to show that its performance is at least as good as other approaches, even by a small amount. If you can't do that, then you are just spinning your wheels.

In such "failed" cases, however, it is also possible to salvage something from the effort, perhaps enough for a degree. If you can show that an approach once thought valuable is, in fact, worthless it can be a useful contribution to scholarship.

But it isn't "time spent" that is the value in research. It is what you add to the knowledge base of humanity.

Comment: "it is necessary to provide evidence of the value of your programs and designs". Sure thing, otherwise what's the point of designing it in the first place.